# Is there a way to normalize emoji size and width?

Tags: css

2 issues with this particular example:

- different emojis have different horizontal "whitespace" which means that if I add `margin-right` to separate wide emojis from numbers, some emojis have natural "whitespace" and space gets weirdly big
- emoji size is very different on MacBook 2880x1800 (15.4 inch) and external 2560x1440 (27 inch) monitor relative to the number besides it - emojis are much bigger on external monitor for some reason

Is there a way to normalize these issues (especially the 2nd one)?

**PS!** I know about using image emojis as a trick to get around these kinds of issues but this question is about native emojis.

#### Screenshots

1. MacBook display

[image]

2. External monitor

[image]

```css
.item {
  font-family: Arial;
  background: #eee;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.emoji {
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="emojis">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="emoji">❓</span>
    <span>123</span>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <span class="emoji">⁉️</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  
    <div class="item">
    <span class="emoji"></span>
    <span>732</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even using other fonts (like Noto Emoji Color) doesn't seem to solve this: https://jsfiddle.net/8850s/64m25gts/3/

Answer (score 0):

Does writing emojis in HEX-codes help them stay the same size across both displays?

```html
<span class="emoji">&#10067</span>
<span class="emoji">&#x203D</span>
<span class="emoji">&#129300</span>
```

I was thinking the Retina display on Macbook, displays pixels differently (double pixel per pixel) and sometimes causes issues, especially on emojis. Maybe changing emoji differently for retina-display can help using @media tag

```
 @media
    only screen and ( -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 ),
    only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 ),
    only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2 ),
    only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 ),
    only screen and ( min-resolution: 96dpi ),
    only screen and ( min-resolution: 1.5dppx ) {
//codehere
}
```